# Why is so hard to use external bibliography with mpdi style?

Tags: bibtex, mdpi

```
\documentclass[applsci,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex]{Definitions/mdpi} 

%=================================================================
% MDPI internal commands
\firstpage{1} 
\makeatletter 
\setcounter{page}{\@firstpage} 
\makeatother
\pubvolume{1}
\issuenum{1}
\articlenumber{0}
\pubyear{2021}
\copyrightyear{2020}
%\externaleditor{Academic Editor: Firstname Lastname} % For journal Automation, please change Academic Editor to "Communicated by"
\datereceived{} 
\dateaccepted{} 
\datepublished{} 
\hreflink{https://doi.org/}

\begin{document}

 \externalbibliography{yes}
 \bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document} 

*Error message* 

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

Style definition

```
\chicagostylejournals{%
\bibliographystyle{Definitions/chicago2}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{x}{}{}%
}{%
\bibliographystyle{Definitions/mdpi}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{n}{}{,}%
}%

\def\@externalbibliography{}
\newcommand{\externalbibliography}[1]{\gdef\@externalbibliography{#1}}
\def\@reftitle{}
\newcommand{\reftitle}[1]{\gdef\@reftitle{#1}}
```

MDPI style can be found in [mdpi](https://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex)

Comment: Well, first of all since the `mdpi` class is not well known (it is not on CTAN) you should probably start by explaining where others can get that style. Then at least they will have a chance to help you. As this question sits now we have no idea what you are complaining about.

Comment: Thank you. Link added

Comment: You are not citing anything and this nothing proper gets written to the `.bbl` file only an empty `thebibilography` env and that will complain about a missing `\item`

Comment: I see. What do you think the journal want authors to do with the provided file? I don't experience this with other journals.

Comment: No idea, I find the template to be of low quality (see for example the amount of warnings coming from just compiling the template). And I don't take templates seriously if they recommend users to use the `[H]` specifier for floats.

Comment: BTW: you tag here is wrong, this template does not use `biblatex`, it uses standard `bibtex`, you might want to change that,

Comment: Ok. tag edited.

Comment: @daleif ,
I managed to generate references  but publication year is boldface only for the first reference. It should have been boldface for every item. I don't know why. 
What do you think the problem is ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I took part of the template and added a `.bib` file and some cites in the document.
Run pdflatex twice + bibtex + pdflatex + pdflatex

[image]

Its is mandatory to choose the journal. I put `languages` in the options of the class.

**Must be** one of the following, for the class to use the `chicago2` style:
admsci, arts, econometrics, economies, genealogy, humanities, ijfs, jintelligence, journalmedia, jrfm, languages, laws, religions, risks, socsci.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex    

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Barker1998,
        Author = {Chris Barker},
        Journal = {Natural Language \& Linguistic Theory},
        Pages = {679-717},
        Title = {Partitives, Double Genitives and Anti-Uniqueness},
        Volume = {16},
        Year = {1998}}
    
    @book{Berwick1985,
        Address = {Cambridge, MA},
        Author = {Berwick, Robert C.},
        Publisher = {MIT Press},
        Title = {Acquisition of syntactic knowledge},
        Year = {1985}}      
        
    @book{Crain1998,
        Address = {Cambridge, Massachusetts},
        Author = {Crain, Stephen and Thornton, Rosalind},
        Publisher = {The MIT Press},
        Title = {Investigations in {U}niversal {G}rammar: A Guide to Experiments on the Acquisition of Syntax and Semantics},
        Year = {1998}}
    
    @article{Dayal2004,
        Author = {Dayal, Veneeta},
        Journal = {Linguistics and Philosophy},
        Number = {4},
        Pages = {393--450},
        Title = {Number Marking and (In)Definiteness in Kind Terms},
        Volume = {27},
        Year = {2004}}
\end{filecontents}


%=================================================================
\documentclass[languages,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex]{Definitions/mdpi} % MUST choose the journal !!!

%=================================================================
% MDPI internal commands
\firstpage{1} 
\makeatletter 
\setcounter{page}{\@firstpage} 
\makeatother
\pubvolume{1}
\issuenum{1}
\articlenumber{0}
\pubyear{2021}
\copyrightyear{2020}
%\externaleditor{Academic Editor: Firstname Lastname} % For journal Automation, please change Academic Editor to "Communicated by"
\datereceived{} 
\dateaccepted{} 
\datepublished{} 
\hreflink{https://doi.org/} % If needed use \linebreak
%------------------------------------------------------------------
% Full title of the paper (Capitalized)
\Title{Title}

% MDPI internal command: Title for citation in the left column
\TitleCitation{Title}

% Author Orchid ID: enter ID or remove command
\newcommand{\orcidauthorA}{0000-0000-0000-000X} % Add \orcidA{} behind the author's name
%\newcommand{\orcidauthorB}{0000-0000-0000-000X} % Add \orcidB{} behind the author's name

% Authors, for the paper (add full first names)
\Author{Firstname Lastname $^{1,\dagger,\ddagger}$\orcidA{}, Firstname Lastname $^{1,\ddagger}$ and Firstname Lastname $^{2,}$*}

% MDPI internal command: Authors, for metadata in PDF
\AuthorNames{Firstname Lastname, Firstname Lastname and Firstname Lastname}

% MDPI internal command: Authors, for citation in the left column
\AuthorCitation{Lastname, F.; Lastname, F.; Lastname, F.}
% If this is a Chicago style journal: Lastname, Firstname, Firstname Lastname, and Firstname Lastname.

% Affiliations / Addresses (Add [1] after \address if there is only one affiliation.)
\address{%
    $^{1}$ \quad Affiliation 1; e-mail@e-mail.com\\
    $^{2}$ \quad Affiliation 2; e-mail@e-mail.com}

% Contact information of the corresponding author
\corres{Correspondence: e-mail@e-mail.com; Tel.: (optional; include country code; if there are multiple corresponding authors, add author initials) +xx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx (F.L.)}

% Current address and/or shared authorship
\firstnote{Current address: Affiliation 3} 
\secondnote{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

% Abstract (Do not insert blank lines, i.e. \\) 
\abstract{A single paragraph of about 200 words maximum. For research articles, abstracts should give a pertinent overview of the work. We strongly encourage authors to use the following style of structured abstracts, but without headings: (1) Background: place the question addressed in a broad context and highlight the purpose of the study; (2) Methods: describe briefly the main methods or treatments applied; (3) Results: summarize the article's main findings; (4) Conclusion: indicate the main conclusions or interpretations. The abstract should be an objective representation of the article, it must not contain results which are not presented and substantiated in the main text and should not exaggerate the main conclusions.}

% Keywords
\keyword{keyword 1; keyword 2; keyword 3 (List three to ten pertinent keywords specific to the article; yet reasonably common within the subject discipline.)} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    The introduction should briefly place the study in a broad context and highlight why it is important. It should define the purpose of the work and its significance. The current state of the research field should be reviewed carefully and key publications cited. Please highlight controversial and diverging hypotheses when necessary. Finally, briefly mention the main aim of the work and highlight the principal conclusions. As far as possible, please keep the introduction comprehensible to scientists outside your particular field of research.
    
\begin{itemize}     
    
    \item   \cite{Barker1998,Berwick1985}
    
    \item   \citet{Barker1998}
    
    \item   \citep{Crain1998}
    
    \item   \citep[see][]{Barker1998}
    
    \item   \citealt{Dayal2004}
    
    \item   \citenum{Barker1998}    
    
\end{itemize}       
    
\end{paracol}

\reftitle{References}

 \externalbibliography(yes) % sets the margins 

\bibliography{\jobname}  % use the file \jobname.bib

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much